# How do I change the order of divs in my responsive design while 2 of them are in a container?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have the following layout on desktop (first screenshot):

[image]

For small screens, I want Div 2 first, then Div 1 and then Div 3.

The problem is that Div 2 and Div 3 are in a container div because otherwise they would not wrap but be next to each other. Because of that I can't use the order function of flexbox. I kind of have to get the divs out of the container, then I could use the order function.

This is what I tried but of course it doesn't work because Div 2 and Div 3 are locked together.  (screenshot 2)

[image]

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
border: solid;
}

.div1 {
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
background-color: lightblue;
}

.div2 {
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
background-color: lightgreen;
}

.div3 {
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
background-color: rgb(238, 144, 188);
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
.container {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.div1 {
  order: 2;
}

.div2 {
  order: 1;
}

.div3 {
    order: 3;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="div1">
        <h2>Div 1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="right-container">
        <div class="div2">
            <h2>Div 2</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="div3">
            <h2>Div 3</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why don't you use the same method by using order in right-container

Comment: you could use .right-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
} and then your order .div2 {
    order: 2;
  }
  .div3 {
      order: 1;
  }and this for your @media (max-width: 600px)

Comment: Just tried it this way can not work as div2 and div3 are wrapped together. You Should use display:contents as suggested below by @A Haworth

Comment: display: contents causes an element's children to appear as if they were direct children of the element's parent, ignoring the element itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use display: contents on right-container. Its children will then be treated as part of the flex and the orders will be taken into account.

```html
<style>
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border: solid;
  }
  
  .div1 {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
  
  .div2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
  }
  
  .div3 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgb(238, 144, 188);
  }
  
  @media (max-width: 600px) {
    .container {
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    .div1 {
      order: 2;
    }
    .div2 {
      order: 1;
    }
    .div3 {
      order: 3;
    }
    .right-container {
      display: contents;
    }
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="div1">
      <h2>Div 1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="right-container">
      <div class="div2">
        <h2>Div 2</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="div3">
        <h2>Div 3</h2>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is amazing. Thanks so much. What a difference just one line of code can make :)